# Automatic css styles depending on text lines

Tags: html, css, browser, opera

I have a problem with css styling for different browsers. I think it has only to do with opera (found this problem with opera only, tested with opera, firefox and chrome).
So I have a pages, where are unordered lists, and every list bullet is different image (but same size). I aligned images and text in every li element, that text is at center (horizontally by image). Every li has text of one line or two lines. When there is li with two lines of text I don't need to use top padding, just bottom padding. When there is one line text li, I use both top and bottom paddings, to align text properly.

It seemed fine with opera, but when I openerp chrome and firefox, some li text was in 2 lines where same li text on opera was in one line. The problem with opera is, that it changes text spacing depending on how much view is zoomed. Both chrome and firefox doesn't change text spacing doesn't matter how much page is zoomed.

To make it more clear, here are example how it looks on opera depending on how much it is zoomed:
[image: Opera view]

My css styles used for unorded list:

```
li.top{
padding-top:9px;
}
li.bottom0{
padding-bottom:6px;
}
li.bottom {
    padding-bottom: 13px;
}
    li.bottom2{
padding-bottom:15px;
}

.li-meetings {
    list-style-type: none;
    background:url(wp-content/uploads/2012/07/calendar.gif) no-repeat;
    padding-left: 50px;
} //all li element styles are the same, just differs uploaded image
```

So the question would be is there any way, to change css styles depending on how much text lines li has (and changing it dynamically when zooming in and out). Or maybe there is some better more simple way?

Comment: You can achieve the same effect in Firefox as in Opera, by choosing "Zoom only text" under "View"->"Zoom"; you really shouldn't have classes that depend on how much lines are required to display the text; what happens on smaller screen sizes? I guess the text will wrap into multiple line – can your CSS handle those cases?

Comment: Ok, so how can I handle that text, so it is properly showed on major browsers? I mean if I change padding to make look good on one browser, on the other li elements goes too close together or too far away from each other

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't rely on text boxes dimensions.
Try using generic solutions like this one: http://jsfiddle.net/jhmVf/3/

Comment: I tried this approach, but for some reason it doesn't align right (in wordpress). I set everything you showed, but text goes lower than an image for some reason..